# GridBagLayout transpose

Tags: java, swing

is it possible to transpose a GridBagLayout dynamically? At the moment I have a JPanel with 3 rows and 1 column. If the panel gets resized and becomes wider, I want the layout to be transposed to 1 row and 3 columns.

Comment: This sounds like a FlowLayout to me.

Comment: No, `GridBagLayout` cannot handle that. However, `WrapLayout` will do that for you marvelously: http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/06/wrap-layout/ . `FlowLayout` works in some case for wrapping, but not always.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware of `WrapLayout`, it worked like I expected to.